# build python extension with boost build

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, boost-build

I'm trying to use boost.python and build a python extension from c++.

My cpp file use a function named 'BZ2_bzopen' which is in the library 'libbz2' under standard path (/usr/lib/). However, when I try to build the extension using boost build following [the instruction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/example/quickstart/Jamroot), I received an error said:

```
====== BEGIN OUTPUT ======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CrossTrade.py", line 11, in <module>
    from custom_c import GoThroughFile
ImportError: /home/jliu/toolpak/custom_c.so: undefined symbol: BZ2_bzopen

EXIT STATUS: 1
====== END OUTPUT ======
```

This seems to me as an error comes from not linking to the library, which is almost the same as if I compile the cpp file without the '-lbz2' command.

Anyone could offer some help on solving it, please?

Comment: How do you import the library in your cpp file?

Comment: @jozzas #include <bzlib.h> the header file is under /usr/include/ directory

Comment: How did you link to the library libbz2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you did not link to `libbz2`? In that case, follow the instructions in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial.html#bbv2.tutorial.prebuilt to see how to link to libraries.